# Android Studio Java Syntax Highlighting Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, syntax-highlighting

In Android Studio (Version 1.1.0) I'm having issues getting it to highlight `.java` syntax properly. It is currently only highlighting Keywords, commas, semicolons, and comments. Other file types such as `.xml` are highlighted properly.

I've tried the following things...

1. Reinstalling Android Studio Removing any personal settings
2. In `Settings -> Editor` Changed the colors to anything to see if it
   worked, under General and Java
3. `File -> Invalidate Caches`
4. Under File Types I've declared my file as a Java source file.
5. Made sure Power Save Mode was turned OFF.

Comment: [Is the file located in a source root?](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html)

Comment: Yup! It is located in root. I'll take a look at the link. Thanks.

Comment: That was indeed the issue, I've submitted my answer. Thanks makoto!

Comment: i have changed my kotlin-gradle-plugin version from 1.5.21 to 1.5.20 in classpath of build.gradle of app and its working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.java` file was located in the root directory. I moved the file to the directory `src/main/java/org.we/` and the syntax started working.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Android Studio 2.2.3, but I don't exactly understand the answer you submitted. Where should the Java source files be located relative to the source root for the syntax highlighting to work? Right now my files are right in the source root directory, and nothing works.

Comment: same. need a slightly more detailed answer

Answer (score 28):

You should do invalidate caches and restart. It will work.

Comment: Nope, didn't help. This started happening after I updated to Flamingo.

Comment: @MarkusK It works with Giraffe. try to update the newer version

Comment: It also worked for me on Giraffe version

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this problem today.  In my case it was caused by Android Studio changing my "MainActivity.java" file from a Class to a Singleton.
If the file is a Class its icon in the editor or project listing will have a "c" in a light blue circle. If it is a Singleton it has a "j" in a grey rectangle.
To resolve it I did the following:

1. copied the file's contents into notepad
2. deleted the singleton file BUT I did not select "safe delete" since I don't want Android Studio to do anything clever
3. created a new Java Class file with the same name as the original file
4. replaced the contents  of the new file with what I put into notepad in step 1

Then everything started working again.

Before this I'd tried the invalidation/restart and disabling power save mode but they did not work for me.  I even tried rebooting my computer several times.

Comment: You saved my day! I just tried that and everything just started working again!

Comment: This helped me, I think that Android Studio (InteliJ IDEA?) get confused by changing a kotlin interface into an abstract class?!

Answer (score 6):

To solve this kind of issue, I had to trigger:
File -> Repair IDE

Answer (score 3):

To quickly refresh or enable syntax highlighting, I accidentally did:
`Ctrl + Alt + S` to go to settings, then in `Plugins -> Installed`
disable any plugin and then Enable it and Apply.

This worked for me.